# Check repeating keys and sum there values in multiple objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I check in multiple objects if the key is the same in other objects and then sum there values.

For example in this case I want to sum all values for A then B.

```
[{
    "firstObject": 1,
    "subObjects": [{
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2
    }, {
        "C": 3,
        "D": 1
    }]
}, {
    "firstObject": 2,
    "subObjects": [{
        "A": 0,
        "C": 5
    }, {
        "B": 2,
        "D": 2
    }]
}]
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Create an empty object. Loop over all the subObjects of all the firstObjects. If the key does not exist in the object you created before, add it with the value  of that key. If it does exist, add the keys value to its value. Maybe 5 lines of code using `array.reduce()`

Comment: I want to store the sum in a variable... like:

let A = 1; let B=4; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce`, for each key in `subObject` object, sum there value and add it in an object.

```js
const data = [{ "firstObject": 1, "subObjects": [{ "A": 1, "B": 2 }, { "C": 3, "D": 1 } ] }, { "firstObject": 2, "subObjects": [{ "A": 0, "C": 5 }, { "B": 2, "D": 2 } ] } ],
    result = data.reduce((r,{subObjects}) => {
      subObjects.forEach(o => {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
          r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + o[k];
        });
      });
      return r;
    },{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce()` method and then return object as a result. You can also use object destructuring on that result `let {A, B} = result` to get values in separate variables.

```js
const data = [{"firstObject":1,"subObjects":[{"A":1,"B":2},{"C":3,"D":1}]},{"firstObject":2,"subObjects":[{"A":0,"C":5},{"B":2,"D":2}]}];
const result = data.reduce((r, {subObjects}) => {
  subObjects.forEach(({A, B}) => {
    if(A) r.A = (r.A || 0) + A
    if(B) r.B = (r.B || 0) + B
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using the function `reduce` to sum values and an array of `targets` to select specific values, is this case, only `[A, B]`

```js
var array = [{    "firstObject": 1,    "subObjects": [{        "A": 1,        "B": 2      },      {        "C": 3,        "D": 1      }    ]  },  {    "firstObject": 2,    "subObjects": [{        "A": 0,        "C": 5      },      {        "B": 2,        "D": 2      }    ]  }],
    targets = ['A', 'B'],
    result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
       targets.forEach(t => a[t] = c.subObjects.reduce((aa, ac) => aa + (ac[t] || 0), a[t] || 0));
       return a;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/egomezr/pen/dmLLwP.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const data = [{
    "firstObject": 1,
    "subObjects": [{
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2
    }, {
        "C": 3,
        "D": 1
    }]
}, {
    "firstObject": 2,
    "subObjects": [{
        "A": 0,
        "C": 5
    }, {
        "B": 2,
        "D": 2
    }]
}];

let result = data.reduce((r,{subObjects})=>[...r,...subObjects],[]).reduce((r,{A,B})=>{
 r['A']+=+(A||0);
 r['B']+= +(B||0);
 return r;
},{A:0,B:0});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```